# Is placing all setters of derived class to util class a good design?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I read some codes like this:

```
public class Base {
    protected Map<String, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<>();
    public Map<String, Object> getAttrMap() {
        return this.attrMap;
    }
}

public class DerivedA extends Base{}

public class DerivedB extends Base{}

public class Util {
    public void setDerivedAAttrX(Base base, Object object) {
        base.getAttrMap().put("DERIVEDA_X", object);
    }
    public void setDerivedAAttrY(Base base, Object object) {
        base.getAttrMap().put("DERIVEDA_Y", object);
    }
    public void setDerivedBAttrX(Base base, Object object) {
        base.getAttrMap().put("DERIVEDB_X", object);
    }
    public void setDerivedAttrZ(Base base, Object object) {
        base.getAttrMap().put("DERIVED_Z", object);
    }
}
```

I asked the implementor of those codes why design like this, here is his answer:

1. We can't let those setters in `Base`, because it's set derived attributes.
2. If we move those setters to corresponding derived class, it's hard to handle `setDerivedAttrZ`.(Note that it can set attribute Z for both `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`)we may have a `Base` reference and we will set attribute Z. We know it's `DerivedA` or `DerivedB` indeed, but don't know it's which one exactly. So we can't cast it to derived class and call derived setters.
3. Since place these setters in `Base` or derived class both have some shortcomings, he comes to a `Util` class to handle those setters.

So my question, is it a good design for that case?

Comment: What is the point of empty derived classes? They are exactly the same as `Base` unless you aren't showing us some parts of the code.

Comment: I will say not because if the purpose of `Util` class is to update the state of `Base`, then `Base#getAttrMap` must not be public because any class could access to this method and update the state as it wants/needs, even clear the map by using `Base#getAttrMap#clear`. In fact, there's no need for the other classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` if they won't add any value to this design.

Comment: Storing attributes in a map like this is generally not a good idea. If you know all the keys in advance, why use a map? Your sample looks suspiciously like an [inner platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: @RogueCSDev In the real case, there are many methods and fields in those derived class.

Comment: That seems extremely odd and breaks many OO principles. Perhaps with a less fictional example we could help you better. From where those Util methods are invoked? As it is right now, DerivedB could be associated in the base's map of a DerivedA instance... does that make any sense? It's quite hard to figure out the use case from the code you posted and therefore the real problematic.

Comment: What if I call `Util.setDerivedBAttrX( new DerivedA(), 42 );`? Neither parameters offer any type safety.

Comment: You'll get more useful answers if you state what Base and DerivedA, DerivedB truly are.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is bad design. The basic of object-oriented programming is to call methods on objects, and not helper functions to which objects and method parameters are passed.

Answer (score 1):

*Guess.* This reeks of several classes having miscellaneous capabilities, some shared.
And untyped at that.

An improvement would be to use an interface with capability and use that as key.

```
public class Base {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<>();

    protected <T> void add(Class<T> clazz, T object);

    /** @return null when not available. */
    public <T> T lookup(Class<T> clazz) {
        Object object = attrMap.get(clazz);
        return clazz.cast(object);
    }
}
```

For the lookup one could use `Optional<T>` instead of a null result.

*About the original:*

The string constants and aggregation might be too much boiler code, circumstantial coding.